# Read specific lines and columns from file using Java

Tags: java

I have a text file which looks like this :

```
   A  B  C  D
A  5  7  10 2
B  1  5  4  20
C  10 1  8  4
D  5  7  4  2
```

So it is supposed to be a matrix and what I want to do is :

1) To get the vectors names (which can be easily done by reading the first line).

2) To visualize only the numbers.

3) To store the numbers in a 2D array.

I already did the first step, remains the second and the third one.

This is my code :

**LectureFichier.java :**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LectureFichier {

    public void lireFichier() {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile"));

            sCurrentLine = br.readLine();

            System.out.println("*******************Lignes*******************");

            String[] nomsAuteurs = sCurrentLine.split(" ");

            for(String auteur : nomsAuteurs) {
                System.out.println(auteur);
            }

            System.out.println("*******************Colonnes*******************");

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] colonnes = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
                for(String colonne : colonnes) {
                    System.out.println(colonne);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Main.java :**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LectureFichier lectureFichier = new LectureFichier();

        lectureFichier.lireFichier();

    }

}
```

When I run this code, it gives me a result like this :

`A57102B15420C10184D5742`

It is because of this paragraphe :

```
for(String colonne : colonnes) {
    System.out.print(colonne);
}
```

A `println(colonne)` will have every split in a different line.

What I want for now is to be able to have something like this :

```
5  7  10 2
1  5  4  20
10 1  8  4
5  7  4  2
```

What did I do wrong? and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be,

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] colonnes = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
            for(int i=1; i<colonnes.length; i++ ) {
                System.out.print(colonnes[i]+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println(); 
        }
```

for the output you expecting.

You should print all the elements in one line in for loop and then print a newline for the next line you read from the file.